# How can I name the device and measured value under certain measurement point of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am trying to understand the data structure of Apache IoTDB, and now have a measuring point in Apache IoTDB named `root.aa.bb.cc.dd`. Then I want to ask does the device name I set have to be `root.aa.bb.cc`? And does the measured value name can only be named `dd`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you set the measuring point name in Apache IoTDB, then due to tree structure settings in IoTDB, the name of devices and measuring values need to be corresponding to the upper layer names.